# Transparent colors with dbgrid

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a row color have 74% transparency.

**My code:**

```
TDBGrid(sender).canvas.brush.color := RGB(0,176,240);
```

But I can't figure out where to add transparency to brush?

Comment: Please provide some more information regarding what you have behind the `TDBGrid` 
 or its rows that you want to be partly visible? The answer depends on this. Also, is this VCL or FMX

Comment: Vcl. And just the background color of the rows

Comment: But then I don't understand why you are concerned with transparency. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268412/2292722) showing how to specify the background color in the `OnDrawColumnColumnCell()` event (note, you need to set `DBGrid1.DefaultDrawing := False;`)

Comment: In case you mean to blend your color with the standard gray color of forms, you could convert to HSL color model and change saturation to 26, which converted back to RGB gives RGB(89, 135, 151). Or, if you want to blend your color with a white background, you could convert to HSV model and change saturation to 26, which conversted back to RGB gives RGB(178, 223, 240). The latter, IMO, looks better as a background color. (Disclaimer: I have no formal knowledge about the color spaces mentioned, just throwing out my layman ideas on the matter.)

Answer (score 0):

gdi+ can support alpha channel for color, you can use gdi+ functions in any canvas

Comment: This is a comment to the original post (if you had the comment privilege), but it's not an answer as currently posted.