How can one change the default editing window colours in a dbGrid?
I'm using Delphi Tokyo and Devexpress Library V18 from around 2015 or so. When I load a DBGrid and then edit the values, the 'edit window' is white text on a blue background no matter how I paint the grid cell.
I have tried using events such as 'OnFocus', 'OnInitEdit' etc to change the focussed grid cell colours but these get over-ridden by the default 'in place editor' such that the cell value is highlighted once again white on blue on top of the cell background colour I've chosen.
I'm also using DevExpress Skin Editor but can't find any setting to override the default in-place editor styles.
I've used Delphi, more off than on, since Delphi V2, mostly for 'in-house' software for companies I have worked for and a few 'freebee' programs for the industry I work in, and have not been overly concerned with this behaviour before. I'm not a trained programmer, just picked it up over the years.
Thank you.

This sounds similar, does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27026043/18667225 ?

I guess by "DBGrid" you mean a cxGrid (as you're specifying a DevEx version) . In this case you should assign a style to the GridView's Styles.Selection property. Probably it's the easiest to use a style repository for that. See https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/171054/ExpressQuantumGrid/task-based-help/setting-the-grid-s-appearance

Uli, changes to the skin properties have no effect on the in-place editor. They change the colour of the focussed grid cell but it is over written by the editor itself.
BTW, all the DevEx supplied 'demo' skins do exactly the same thing as do the few  other 'DBManagers' I've tried (such as SQLite Manager). MS Excel doesn't do it.
Yes, it's a cxDBGrid. Also tried the standard Delphi DBGrid and it does the same. I guess the editors are 'Standard' Windows editors and the text/background is predefined by Windows itself.

Hi Markus. Thanks but the reference is slightly different. When editing a cell value the editor 'window' is white on blue on top of the colours I've set for the focussed cell. When not editing the cell the colours of the cells are as specified by the skin.

Hi Markus. Thanks but the reference is slightly different. When editing a cell value the editor 'window' partially  replaces the programmed colours with a white on blue window partially (but not completely) covering the cell. Sort of a 'window within a window'.  This only happens when the value is selected for editing. If there's just the cursor there then the cell colour is 'as specified' in the 'OnCustomDraw' or "OnInitEdit' Is it possible to post pictures on this forum. Would be easier to demonstrate.

Having now paid more attention to the editors on Windows programs it would appear that the Editing Window colours are defined by the Windows operating system. I'm quite amazed that having used Windows for decades I'd never picked this up. I guess that one gets accustomed to it and it passes without notice
It would therefore appear that the only way to change the standard Windows edit window is to change the operating system standard colours by directly interfacing with the windows system. Something which I'm hesitant to do not knowing what 'knock-on' effect it might have.
